# Create a Facebook App using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

I want to create a Facebook App using codeiginiter but I've got always the same error :

In french : L’URL fournie n’est pas autorisée par la configuration de l’application.: Une ou plusieurs URL fournies ne sont pas autorisées par les paramètres de l’application. Elle(s) doi(ven)t correspondre à l’URL du site ou du Canevas, ou le domaine doit être un sous-domaine de l’un des domaines de l’application.

Google translate in english : The URL provided is not permitted by the application configuration. One or more URLs provided are not permitted by the settings of the application. She must match the URL of the site or Canvas, or the field must be a subdomain of one of the fields of application.

Here my code :

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
{
    parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_REQUEST );
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->config->load("facebook",TRUE);
    $config = $CI->config->item('facebook');
    $this->load->library('Facebook', $config);

    // Try to get the user's id on Facebook
    $userId = $this->facebook->getUser();

    // If user is not yet authenticated, the id will be zero
    if($userId == 0){
        // Generate a login url
        $data['url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email', 'redirect_uri' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/dressthingstests/'));
        $this->load->view('app/index', $data);
    } else {
        // Get user's data and print it
        $user = $this->facebook->api('/me');
        print_r($user);
    }
}
}
```

The url var is not empty : https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fxxxxxxtests%2F&state=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=email

Any idea ? :/
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to read this Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433438/facebook-login-sample-in-codeigniter/15433469#15433469

Comment: It's not for a login use, it's for a FB App...

Comment: Is your Redirect URL is working corectly?

Comment: The redirect_uri is the page of my app... it's a copy past